# How can I edit the data source in the information link in Spotfire?

Tags: spotfire

Some of my source table names in my postgreSQL database have changed. Spotfire's information link can't load the table now.
In the Edit function of the information link there is no possibility to change the data source path or the table name.
The Data Connection Properties does not contain any entry.

Any ideas what I can do except creating new information links? (That would mean I have to recreate all calculated columns etc.)